# What is wrong with handling async calls after res.send in Express

Tags: express, asynchronous

I was told that it is incorrect to perform any actions that triggered during handling Express request but didn't finished before `res.send`. For instance, send push notifications or saving items in DB without awaiting its finallization. If this statement correct, what could happens in this case?

Example code (assume we do not need **any** validation or anything else here and do not bother about that async operations results, just to demonstrate what I mean):

```
router.get('/push', async (req, res) {
  const data = req.body;

  // Three lines below are async actions     
  db.save(req.body);                                    // Do not await here
  push.send(req.body.device, 1);                        // Do not await here
  remoteLogger.info('received push request', req.body); // Do not await here

  res.status(200).send('ok');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the saving operation (or any other) can fail for some reason and you might want the client to get an error in this case.
If you send a response to the client before the saving operation finishes, you will have no possibility to tell that to the client since the response has been sent and the connection closed.

Comment: Thanks, I know about it. But imagine we do not bother about results. I.e. if it saved or if it failed everything ok. Question mostly about general practice.